# Salesforce Managed Package Design

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, force.com

I have question regarding creating standard objects like lead, opportunity, account in managed package code, since this are heavily used object in all orgs, there might be tone of validation, required field to help each org business process.

My question as a package developer may not aware of the customer org required/validation rules, I know we choose not to run unit test during installation which may not be good idea, or if we create required data in unit test using some dynamic apex like smartfactoryforforce.com in git, it will solve test issues,

how do we create this object in our controller/trigger ? whats are some of the best practice done my ISV vendors?

Comment: I don't think there's a good answer for that. Describe calls will tell you if fields are required but you'd need metadata API to learn about validation rules for example (and good luck parsing them, figuring out what data should be populated). And even then- client org can always have a special validation in a trigger. If you have to create an Opp in code - maybe you could have a checkbox field and ask your clients to change their validations to not run until it's ticked. Or display a form for new Opp using a fieldset so your client can add more fields to it as needed and the save will succeed

Comment: You can ask Salesforce questions directly on salesforce.stackexchange.com